# Not getting error report when failing to connect to database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not getting any error message when I fail to connect to my database. Can anyone tell me why?
It looks fine per https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

````
    ```       
    <?PHP
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "myusername";
    $password = "mypassword";

    try {
     $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase;charset=utf8mb4', $username, 
     $password);
     $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    } 
    catch(PDOException $e) {
    print "An Error occured!" . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
    }
    ?>
    ```
````

Comment: If you `print` anything, like `print "Foo";` as your very first operation, do you see anything?

Comment: The obvious question here is: what makes you think the connection failed? You could check [PDO::errorInfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) before you do anything else.

Comment: No it's not printing 'foo'

Comment: Nooby, then your print is not behaving as you intended. Fix that before you make conclusions about your connection error.

Comment: Thanks Lajos. Didn't have the file extension on my connection include file. Doh!